# Render the selected object fields in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to react and I want to render the logged in user -username in navbar.The navbar.js looks like

```
const Navbar = ({ user, isAuthenticated }) => {
console.log(user)
.......
.......
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Navbar);
```

The console.log(user) returns an object

```
Object { username: "Admin", id: 1, email: "admin@gmail.com" }
```

But when I console.log(user.username) it return -

```
TypeError: user is null
```

So, how can I get those fields like user.username or user.email in react.

Comment: try like this `console.log(user?.username). The reason why you receive user is null is because redux is async. First the initialstate is initialized and then the action

Comment: Oh ! great that worked. Thank you